# "duplicate entry: util/GenericData$EntrySet.class" error when trying to run my app

Tags: java, android

I have tried to clean my project, clean the gradle file, rebuild my project, but when I try to run my app, I get this error:

> TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   util/GenericData$EntrySet.class

How can I fix that?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.name.app"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'}


android {useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'}
```

Comment: You have some overlap in your HTTP libraries, it seems. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.19.0/com/google/api/client/util/GenericData.EntrySet

Comment: oh thank you! @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** You error means you have overlap in your dependencies.

You can cut most of them out.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    // ... this can stay the same
}

ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = "23.4.0"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "10.2.0"
    retrofitVersion = "2.2.0"
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-<SERVICE HERE>:$googlePlayServicesVersion"

    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

---

---

**Explanation**

I doubt you need any of these. You also duplicated JUnit, which does not need compiled outside of the test environment

> ```
> compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
> compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
> compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
> compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
>
> useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
> ```

You already have Retrofit to handle HTTP requests (it is out of beta, by the way, so update it with Gson).

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

It includes OkHttp, so that's why you remove that also.

---

Then, it's unlikely you will ever use every Google Services in a single app.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

Pick the ones you actually use

[Google Play Services | Selectively choose your dependencies](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split)

For example, want maps, then use `compile '... services-maps:<VERSION NUMBER>'`

---

And you can also remove this one because `design` already includes that...

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```